# css reaching another element

Tags: css

can you help me reaching .form class on .right class hover?
I've alredy tried + and ~, but probably I'm doing something wrong.
Here's the code:

```
<div id="searchForm">

  <div id="typeSelector">
    <div class="left"><img src="images/left_arrow.png"></div>
    <div class="middle"><img src="images/typeSelector.png"></div>
    <div class="right"><img src="images/right_arrow.png"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="transform3D">
    <div id="one" class="form"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="transform3D">
    <div id="two" class="form"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="transform3D">
    <div id="three" class="form"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="transform3D">
    <div id="four" class="form"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You cannot do this. You could use Javascript, though.

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. In CSS you could style anything with the class 'form' by adding this line to your css file .form { // put css here }

Comment: As the name suggests, cascading style sheets work in a downward inheritance fashion.
As such, you cannot reach the desired result using plain CSS.
Is there any specific reason why you don't want to use JavaScript for this?

Comment: Ok, thanks for help.... I'm going to use JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution if you can get rid of your #typeSelector div.

Then with the "sibling" selector `~`

`.left:hover ~ .transform3D #one`

But I'm not sure it is working in every browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/NeekGerd/HHtef/